# Struts2: Download File + WaitAndExecute

Tags: java, struts2

I have a little problem:

I have a action configured with these params:

```
<action name="exportCSV" class="it.asd.ExportAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack" />
    <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait"/>
         <result name="success" type="stream">
             <param name="contentType">application/x-zip-compressed</param>
             <param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
             <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${filename}"</param>
             <param name="bufferSize">2048</param>
         </result>
         <result name="wait" type="tiles">waitPage</result>

      <result name="error" type="redirectAction" >visualizzaasd</result>
    </action>
```

I want that, after downloading, page returns to another and not remain on the waitpage.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 1):

You can not now when the file was downloaded. You can add [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to your wait page.

Comment: Has already been added, because the jsp don't retrieve when file is ready.

Comment: So - is this finished or not?

Comment: yes is finished. I want to go to a success page. I've tried a result without name... a global result. With this solution I see the wait page and success page, but the alert for the download don't appear...